# Generic Functions and Protocols in Swift 3.2 failing to infer type

Tags: swift, swift3

Given the following .

```
func doSomething<T: JSONDecodable>() -> [T] { return [] }
```

and a concrete type of `Animal: JSONDecodable` I'm trying to invoke the `doSomething` method without specifying the type of Animal.

The following works: `let result: [Animal] = doSomething()`

The following examples do not:

```
let result: [JSONDecodable] = doSomething() // Cannot convert value of type '_' to closure result 'JSONDecodables'
```

Storing out the type:

```
let savedType = Animal.Type
let result: [savedType] = doSomething() // Use of undeclared type savedType
```

Any suggestions to how to hint the compiler without specifying the concrete type?

Comment: Your method it is already generic what you are asking doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If the most what you desire is to return an array of [JSONDecodable] then don't use generic function at all and all you want is already done.

Comment: @LeoDabus The method is a generic that takes in a protocol. When invoking this method I'd like to not need to specify the concrete type. Alternatively saving out the concrete type in a variable and loading it in later would also be appropriate.

Comment: @MatthewLuiHK Sorry but this is a simplified example of production code. The function does not take in an object of type JSONDecodable in order to simply return back an array. Think of doSomething() as a method that generates those objects without knowing it's concrete type.

Comment: Then what you should use is just simply Any

Comment: I would suggest to add a little more code (executable in a Playground preferably) and be more specific about what your expectations are. As it stands your questions is rather vague.